# Zoom and Anaconda Navigator have weird scaling

Tags: software-installation, scaling

I recently installed Zoom and it is opening up really weird - everything is super zoomed-in. Is there a way to change the resolution of a program? I was wondering if there was a configuration file that zoom was getting its settings from and maybe that file had the resolution incorrect.

[image: zoom resolution not right in Ubuntu]

By the way, I have already tried `sudo apt purge ...` to uninstall it and then manually removed the `~/.zoom` directory, too, but that did not work.

**Edit 1 [Included System Settings]**

Screen Resolution: 1920 x 1080

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

GNOME Version: 3.36.2

Windowing System: X11

**Edit 2 [Installed Anaconda and it is doing the same]**

I just installed Anaconda and opened up Anaconda Navigator, and this is how it's being displayed:

[image: anaconda navigator displaying with incorrect resolution]

Other programs, like File Manager, Chrome, LibreOffice, etc. are displaying okay.

Comment: In your post, include information on your current screen resolution, Ubuntu version and  desktop environment.

Comment: @vanadium just added them. thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Fixing Zoom's Scaling Issue**: Check out [u/190](https://www.reddit.com/user/190n/)'s [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/hbo6pf/zoom_is_huge/).

TL;DR of the post: Apparently, Zoom started doing that after some recent update. To fix things, you just have to set `autoScale` to `false` in Zoom's config file, which is `~/.config/zoomus.conf`.

**Fixing Anaconda Navigator's Scaling Issue**: Turns out my Anaconda Navigator was not displaying right because it was configured by default to automatically scale up on high DPI displays, and when I disabled that option things went back to normal. Here are the steps you can follow to disable it:

1. Run `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.5 anaconda-navigator` to open Anaconda Navigator. (If you run `anaconda-navigator` without a `QT_SCALE_FACTOR`, it might run too zoomed-in for you to follow the steps below)
2. Go to File > Preferences, and uncheck "Enable High DPI Scaling".
3. Close Anaconda Navigator.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Under Ubuntu 20.04.3, I tried it and it worked. 
But immediately after a `conda update --all`, which included `anaconda-navigator-2.1.1  py37_0  5.3 MB`, it stopped working.

Comment: Does not work with Ubuntu Mate 22.04.

Comment: Huh, setting `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` in the system environment variables (probably also for user variables) also works in Windows. Cool.

Answer (score 4):

> Fix for anaconda-navigator scaling issue.

If the preferences window was too big to save/apply the changes using the GUI.

Then, follow the following steps:

1. *open* preference file `sudo nano ~/.anaconda/navigator/anaconda-navigator.ini`
2. *update* `enable_high_dpi_scaling = False`
3. *restart* anaconda-navigator

Hope this will solve the issue.

EDIT:
As per Sublimer's comment for some users,
changing `enable_high_dpi_scaling = None` works.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me. Ubuntu 20.04 same issue.

Comment: enable_high_dpi_scaling = False has no effect.

Comment: `enable_high_dpi_scaling = None` not `False`
thank you

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 worked flawlessly for me !!!! thank you

Comment: Does not work with Ubuntu Mate 22.04